# inserting the item in the list in specific format

Tags: python, list

I have two list list1 and list2 (given in the code), i have to insert the list2 in such a way that it produces in the following format:

[image: output]

The code which i have return is:

```
list1 = ["c","o",["m",["p","u",["t","e"],"o"],"g"],"r","a","m"]

list2 = ["r","p","r"]

for i in list1:
  for j in i:
    for k in list2:
      if ord(k)<ord(j):
        list1.insert(list1.index(j),k)
```

Can anyone help me to have the right code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first find the inner-most list and then eventually append your list to this `inner-most-list`:

```
list1 = ["c","o",["m",["p","u",["t","e"],"o"],"g"],"r","a","m"]

list2 = ["r","p","r"]

inner_most_list = list1
found = False
while not found:
    for index, el in enumerate(inner_most_list):
        print(index, el)
        if isinstance(el, list):
            inner_most_list = el
            break
        if index == len(inner_most_list)-1:
            # Reached end of recursive-list possibilities
            found = True
            break

inner_most_list.extend(list2)
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'o', ['m', ['p', 'u', ['t', 'e', 'r', 'p', 'r'], 'o'], 'g'], 'r', 'a', 'm'
```

**The code is generic, and should work for other test-cases too.**

Comment: thanx, you explained it nicely. :)

Comment: @JonardanCena If you found the answer helpful, please choose as best answer to help others in similar situations